What will happen if token has expired in Microsoft.Identity.Web
What I'm using
I'm using IAuthorizationHeaderProvider to get the access token.
From where does the library get the access token?
As I know, the ASP.NET Core OIDC authentication can store the access token into the cookie. Does the lib get the access token and refresh token from cookie?
What will happen if the refresh token expired?
What I guess is that the lib will auto use the refresh token to get a new access token. But what if the refresh token has even expired? Is the authentication cookie and the HttpContext.User still valid, and what will happen if I call the IAuthorizationHeaderProvider.
Can I get the latest access token with latest claims?
A common use case is that an application will assign a role to a user programmatically. The problem here is when the role assignment is finished, I think the authentication cookie won't refresh. So the [Authorize(Roles=["NewAssigned"])] wont work until we can get the latest claims and set the cookie.
So, when calling the IAuthorizationHeaderProvider, will we get the latest access token with latest claims? If not, how to get the latest token, and how to refresh users claims for AuthorizeAttribute.

I think you need a re-login for new claims.
